# emacs window(frame) disappears at start

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I use emacs on ubuntu 15.04,and my emacs config file is from https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d, with some of my own configuration file.

When I run emacs from shell or start icon, it start normal, show some loading information, and ask a question about desktop file already been used by some pid. Neither answer yes or no, the frame goes on until the last step, it just disappears. There are process pid still, but the emacs frame can not be found no where.

If I start emacs from shell command, and use -q parameter, not loading configuration files, everything is just fine. And I can even load the configuration file by hand after that.

If I start emacs from shell command, with -nw parameter, also it can work.

Any one have any ideas about what is really going on here?

Comment: It seems like something in your configuration file is causing this, but only in window mode. Try commenting out as much as possible of your config file, so that you get the minimal file that still causes the problem. Then copy the remaining commands into the question.

Comment: What @legoscia said. It's up to *you* to narrow down your configuration to locate the problematic code. You do that by using binary search on your init file (and if necessary, on any problematic library it loads). You do that by commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, 31/32,... of your init file. Use command `comment-region`. With a prefix arg it uncomments. If you don't do this then it is likely that your question will be closed as unclear or too broad - unless you get lucky and someone guesses what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly what your issue is. I had the same problem myself.

Emacs desktop tries to restore the same windows in the same location as you opened them last time. But the last time you opened Emacs successfully you started it in a different `DISPLAY` (`DISPLAY` is an environment variable in Linux that more or less controls which window manager new windows should be appear in). So, the wrong `DISPLAY` is stored in your `.emacs.desktop` file. When you open Emacs, desktop helpfully opens Emacs in the old `DISPLAY`, which you have no way of viewing.

### Solution

with Emacs closed, open `~/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop`. Inside, you'll see

```
(setq desktop-saved-frameset ... (display . ":1.0") ...)
```

Change that to `(display . ":0.0")`, and open Emacs again.

### Making it never happen again

Put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq desktop-restore-frames nil)
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem get solved. I comment two lines last changed in my configure file, the problem disappear.  And the .emacs.desktop file is all good now.     Maybe this problem is caused by a historical bad operation, and some cache file mismatch. Since every file is good now, I fail to repeat the problem and find out the original cause of it.  Anyway, now I know how to fix it next time, so, thank you very much.

Comment: JinQian Chen: Make sure you 'accept' an answer when it resolves your problem. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers